# Will the mass affect the speed of the toy car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, friction, speed

Let’s say you have to calculate the speed of a toy car. However you will be adding weights onto the car. The car will be going up a rank with a 20 degree angle. Will the car slow down? If yes why?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually doing a modified version of [Galileo's Pisa Tower Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment).

If the initial speed of the toy car is the same in both experiments, there will be only a little difference. The car is affected by

1. the gravity
2. the pressure of the ramp
3. and by the friction.

(1) and (2) scale linearly by the mass. (3) scales nearly linearly.

This results only a little difference because (3). Probably it would be on the border of the free-eye visibility.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no force acting on the toy car in the direction of motion, it will slow down because of
1)Component of gravitational force mgSin20

2)Friction